# How to judge whether a bipartite graph with weight is separable?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I want to determine whether a bipartite graph is separable when there is a vertex whose weight is less than or equal to the threshold. For example, `0.2` is chosen as a threshold.

[image]

- In figure 1), there is a vertex with red whose weight is less than `0.2`. The bipartite graph can be separated into three subgraphs and the red vertex is copied into the three subgraphs respectively.
- In figure 2), there is also a vertex with red whose weight is less than `0.2`. However, the red edge causes the bipartite graph to not be split into subgraphs.

My idea:

1. copy the vertex(named `lowVer`, red) whose weight is less than or equal to the threshold and link the duplicate vertices to associated vertice respectively(green edges). Associated vertice is the vertices connected to the vertex `lowVer`.
2. disconnect from the vertex `lowVer`(yellow edges).
3. judge whether the bipartite graph is separable by `depth-first-search`

[image]

Is there a better way?

Comment: wouldn't be easier to delete the red vertexes?

Comment: @shukiavraham delete a vertex need two steps: 1. delete the vertex from those vertices associated with the vertex. 2. delete the vertex self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, what you want is to know if a given vertex (the one less than the thresold) is an articulation point or not. An articulation point is a vertex that, when removed from the graph, increase the number of connected components.

If I formulated correctly your problem, then there are many algorithms to find articulation points, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component#Other_algorithms or https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to solve this. 
Let's pick node with 0.1 weight and put it like the root of the graph.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNx0n.png)

now if the leaf node has degree 1 , its separable
else, it's not separable.

Let me know if i am missing something..